# html send GET method Home page request with authorizaiton bearer token and display xmlhttprequest.response (i.e. home page) in a window

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, jwt

I have implemented spring boot security project.

```
Security_Config.java,
```

JwtFilter.java,
JwtUtil.java and etc

I am able to generate a token by sending login page through authenticate service.Subsequenty,I have received the token and stored in`localStorage.setItem("token",http.responseText);` .

After receiving the token i am making xmlhttprequest using GET method for Home page with authorizaiton, bearer with token. i have received xmlhttprequest.response (i.e. home page). i want to show it in CURRENT window by replacing/redirecting `http://127.0.0.1:8080/Login.html to http://127.0.0.1:8080/Home.html`

Comment: "i have received xmlhttprequest.response (i.e. home page)" did you receive the URL for that page?  (i.e. {page: "home page", pageURL: "/"}) if so, you can use `window.location.replace(pageURL)` once you received it.

Comment: Hi, I'm no Java expert, but I'm not seeing a question here. You might like to rephrase your question to make it clearer what you need help with.

Comment: I have received complete Home page. When I am using alert (xmlhttprequest.response) my home page content is visible in alert window.
I have tried window.location.replace(pageURL) but again it is diverted to spring boot authentication filter and error occurred.

i want to show  login pagewindow(/login) to be replaced by Home page(/home) after authentication

Comment: Security_Config extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java